# CGFloat MinimumValue vs CurrentValue

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, cgfloat

I created a custom slider with a uiview class ... everything works fine but I just have a problem ...

in my view controller implements the Custom Slider class this way

**Main ViewController**

```
#pragma mark SMALL STATS
-(KPStatsSlider *)statsSlider {
    if (!_statsSlider) {
        _statsSlider = [[KPStatsSlider alloc] init];
        _statsSlider.minimumValue = 18;
        _statsSlider.maximumValue = 30;
        _statsSlider.currentValue = 12;


        _statsSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:self.statsSlider];

        [self.statsSlider.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:115].active = YES;
        [self.statsSlider.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
        [self.statsSlider.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:70].active = YES;
        [self.statsSlider.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor constant:0].active = YES;

    }
    return _statsSlider;
}
```

as you can see, I can assign the value:
**Current /
Minimum /
Maximum**

In my personalized UIView I implemented this feature to prevent the CurrentValue value being smaller than MinimumValue but I can not get it running can you help me with this?

**Custom Slider UIView**

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self defaultValue];
        [self setupStatsTitle];
        [self trackLine];


        if (self.currentValue <= self.minimumValue) {
            self.currentValue = self.minimumValue;
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: @beyowulf in constraints and addSubview ?

Comment: @beyowulf Ok perfect Thanks a lot, this also applies to uilabel, uiview etc ... ??? Also would you tell me something about my question?

Comment: @beyowulf tell me what you think is best between self.stats and _stats

Comment: Yes, I would use `_stats` in the getter and setter. `self.stats` everywhere else. This is good practice for all obj-c properties.

Comment: @beyowulf Why did you delete your comments?

Comment: @beyowulf So in my case - (KPStatsSlider *) is everything correct as I implemented it? is when i call _stats and even when i call self.stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want

```
if (self.currentValue <= self.minimumValue) {
    self.currentValue = self.minimumValue;
}
```

In the setter of `currentValue`. For example:

```
- (void)setCurrentValue:(CGFloat)currentValue {
    _currentValue = currentValue;
    if (_currentValue < self.minimumValue) {
        _currentValue = self.minimumValue;
    }
    if (_currentValue > self.maximumValue) {
        _currentValue = self.maximumValue
    }
}
```

Your code currently only checks when the slider is initialized, but not if `currentValue` is set later.

In general, I prefer to access an instance variable directly if I’m in that instance variable’s setter/getter to avoid confusion and possible infinite recursion, but your code as written is okay.